# How to get statistics on a large text file of data

Tags: python, numpy, awk, bigdata

I have a collection of large (~100,000,000 line) text files in the format:

```
    0.088293 1.3218e-32 2.886e-07 2.378e-02        21617        28702
    0.111662 1.1543e-32 3.649e-07 1.942e-02        93804        95906
    0.137970 1.2489e-32 4.509e-07 1.917e-02        89732        99938
    0.149389 8.0725e-32 4.882e-07 2.039e-02        71615        69733
    ...
```

And I'd like to find the mean and sum of column 2 and maximum and minimum values of columns 3 and 4, and the total number of lines. How can I do this efficiently using NumPy? Because of their size, `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` are no good (take a long time to execute) since they attempt to read the whole file into memory. In contrast, Unix tools like `awk`:

```
awk '{ total += $2 } END { print total/NR }' <filename>
```

work in a reasonable amount of time.
Can Python/NumPy do the job of `awk` for such big files?

Comment: so you are looking just for a numpy answer? I don't know about this techonlogy, but `awk` can do it very well

Comment: I'm open to an `awk` answer if I can get the other statistics in one pass of the file. I don't know `awk` so well.

Comment: then it would also help to show how the desired output should look like

Comment: I'm not too worried about the precise output format: whitespace delimited values on a single line or `<key> = <val>` pairs on separate lines would both be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say something like:

```
awk '{  total2 += $2
        for (i=2;i<=3;i++) {
            max[i]=(length(max[i]) && max[i]>$i)?max[i]:$i
            min[i]=(length(min[i]) && min[i]<$i)?min[i]:$i
        }
     } END {
           print "items", "average2", "min2", "min3", "max2", "max3"
           print NR, total2/NR, min[2], min[3], max[2], max[3]
     }' file
```

#### Test

With your given input:

```
$ awk '{total2 += $2; for (i=2;i<=3;i++) {max[i]=(length(max[i]) && max[i]>$i)?max[i]:$i; min[i]=((length(min[i]) && min[i]<$i)?min[i]:$i)}} END {print "items", "average2", "min2", "min3", "max2", "max3"; print NR, total2/NR, min[2], min[3], max[2], max[3]}' a | column -t
items  average2     min2        min3       max2        max3
4      2.94938e-32  1.1543e-32  2.886e-07  8.0725e-32  4.882e-07
```

Comment: Might want to check that max[i] contains data as if it is 0 then it will count any negative numbers as larger.

Comment: True point, although I am already doing `max[i]=(max[i] && max[i]>$i)?max[i]:$i`. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Nope, imagine one line had -1, this is now `max[i]`, the next line has zero, `max[i]` is now 0, now if the next line has anything but `null,"",0` then that will be set to max as `max[i]` will fail and so the `&& max[i]>$i` won't be executed defaulting to just setting whatever $i is to be the max value.

Comment: @User112638726 now I see, good one! So by saying `max[i]=(length(max[i])>0 && max[i]>$i)?max[i]:$i` it should be fixed, right?

Comment: Yep that should do it! Don't really need to check if it is more than 0 as it will be `false/0` anyway if it was empty, does make it easier to read though i suppose :) Also it will cause the same problem with min as well but the opposite way round.

Answer (score -1):

loop through the lines and apply regex to extract the data you are looking for, adding it into an initially empty list for each column you desire.

Once you have the column in list form you can apply max(list) min(list) avg(list) functions to the data to get whatever calculations you are interested in.

note: You may need to revise where you added the data to the list and convert the numbers from str to int form so that the max, min, avg functions can operate on them.

Comment: It would be better to calculate the statistics as he went through each row; that way he doesn't need to build the list at all.